# Forbidden (#403) - You are not allowed to perform this action [Yii2]

Tags: yii2

I've tried to add menu `map` in backend-side. I use `yii2-advanced`. This is my “controller” code:

```
public function actionMap()
{
    return $this->render('map');
}
```

But, when I try to access it with this url `http://localhost/yii2advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=site/map`, I've got error message `Forbidden (#403) - You are not allowed to perform this action`. I don't understand why I got this error message, can anybody help me to fix this problem?

Comment: This isn't a php issue, it's a yii issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's caused by [AccessControl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html). Most likely the action `map` is blocked according to access rules. Example of allowing it for all authenticated users:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */ 
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['create', 'update'],
            'rules' => [                
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                // everything else is denied
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Alternatively you can adjust access according to some RBAC roles.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the arogachev's answer:
Paste it in your site controller:

```
   public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```