# Installing Yii2 - 403 Forbidden page

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I installed Yii2 - downloaded archive file from Yii website, put it on server, but when I try to access my page, I get:

> 403 Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this document.

This is probably something stupid that I don't realize of, but have no idea where to search for help. I simply downloaded files and unpacked them in the directory I wanted to.

Comment: Do you use mysite/web/ as url?

Comment: Maybe you need this https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/enable-pretty-urls/

Comment: Pretty URLs are on. When I try to access my page via browser, it returns error 403. When I try to access there something, that doesn't exist, it returns 404. So it knows there are files to show, but doesn't want to show them!

Comment: did you comment the first 2 lines of web/index.php? do you have the right .httacces files at root and web folder?

Comment: I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448409/forbidden-403-you-are-not-allowed-to-perform-this-action-yii2

Comment: I commented them, but nothing has changed. I have no idea where to look for all these files, that looks way harder that I thought earlier.

Comment: uncomment the first 2 lines of web/index.php to  enable debug mode of yii2. Have you rules ( AccessControl) as previous post says?

Comment: I have problems finding that part with Access Control, I've searched through every folder, but I can't find it.

Comment: Look at your controllers, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html look for 'access' behavior as the article writes

Comment: Okay, I found it and changed literally nothing, because everything looks the same as in the example. So, still there is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just unpacked files in to your directory on server, may be you must did this:
[Preparing Application](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#preparing-application)